# What happens if a before trigger action forces a workflow rule and that causes the trigger event again

Tags: trigger, workflow

Please explain if a trigger event which causes a workflow rule to fire and the goes in a loop.
or will it terminate after some update?

Answer (score 2):

This is covered in the [documentation on the order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).

Salesforce has thought of this, and has put safeguards in place to prevent infinite loops.

If a workflow rule on an object, call it ObjectA, has a field update (also on ObjectA, for sake of ease), it will cause the `before update` and `after update` triggers for ObjectA to fire precisely one more time.